# Download/Upload Excel workbook created with openpyxl using dialog box

Tags: python, django, excel, openpyxl, dialog

I'm using Django and Openpyxl to create an app that can write an Excel workbook using data from the app and then save the file locally.

When I used:

```
wb = Workbook()
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

The file was saved in my Django project's root folder.

How can I have the file download to the browser's download folder as opposed to saving directly in the root directory of the app on its server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl provides a function to save a file to a `StringIO` object:

```
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
stream = save_virtual_workbook(wb)
```

However, for larger files it might be preferable to save to somewhere in the file system and let the http server handle the download.

Comment: According to the documentation, this method is now deprecated in favor of using NamedTemporaryFile.